# Describing String swagger response schema in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have created controller which returns json by string, so as I'm using @RestController annotation it transforms it to correct json and it works totally fine.

```
@Api(tags = "Controller")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public MyController (MyService MyService ) {
        this.MyService = MyService ;
    }

    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request", response = ErrorDto.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Location id not found", response = ErrorDto.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal error")
    })
    @ApiOperation(value = "....", tags = {"Alarms"})
    @PostMapping(value = "")
    public String getValuesByJsonString(@RequestBody Request request) {
       eturn MyService.getMyData(request);
    }

}
```

By problem that in swagger I see response as "string" and I would like to see json structure which is returned by jackson after conversion.

Is it possible to specify this structure directly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a `Response` class as per your response structure e.g.

```
public class Response {

    private int status;
    private String data;

    // setter getter
}
```

Now refer this `Response` class in `@ApiOperation` as

```
@ApiOperation(value = "....", tags = {"Alarms"}, response = Response.class)
```

Now response schema corresponding to `Response` class will be generated instead of string.